# Can I force type a variable in python 2.7?

Tags: python, eclipse, python-2.7, pydev

I have a method that return a config object, this object contains variables. Depending on the context it could be a `DevConfig` or a `VmConfig` or a `ProdConfig`. They don't all have the same variables.

I'd like to be able to specify in my code "here it's a VmConfig" to get autocomplete with Eclipse.

Comment: Why are you asking *"in Python 2.7"*? Do you mean *"in Eclipse"*? If those things don't have the same attributes, under general *"duck typing"* rules you shouldn't be passing them interchangeably anyway.

Comment: I mean is there a way to do it in python or in eclipse.
Does the language allow it or is there an eclipse hack?

Comment: Python is strongly *but dynamically* typed, you have to use third party tools to force types. As for what type hints Eclipse accepts, you will have to check its documentation.